# How to improve the performance of the code and to execute it in less time for VBA EXCEL code COUNTIF

Tags: excel, vba, performance, excel-formula, countif

I hope you can help me to optimize this code block in VBA EXCEL. When I execute the block of code with less than 30 thousand records, it takes 3 minutes to execute.

I want your support to validate if there is a possibility to improve the performance of the code and to execute it in less time.

How could I improve that line so that it takes less time to execute? I hope that either of the two blocks of code can be taken as an example.

Thank you very much for your support

```
Sub findduplicates()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet 'always specify a worksheet
      
    Range("BE1") = "Flag_Unico"
    
    With ws.Range("BE2:BE" & ws.Cells(Rows.count, "N").End(xlUp).Row)
        .Formula = "=COUNTIF(BD:BD,BD2)=1"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
            
End Sub
```

This code took '2 min.17 sec to execute and what it does is set a TRUE or FALSE flag. If it is FALSE, it sets the same FLAG to the original and the duplicate

```
Sub findduplicates()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet 'always specify a worksheet
      
    Range("BE1") = "Flag_Unico"
            
    With ws.Range("BE2:BE" & ws.Cells(Rows.count, "N").End(xlUp).Row)
        .Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(BD:BD,BD2)=1,0,1)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    
End Sub
```

This code took '2 min.08 sec to execute and what it does is set a 1 or 0 flag. If it is 0, it sets the same FLAG to the original and the duplicate

Comment: Questions about performance on working code might be best suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: set `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and  Application.ScreenUpdating = True` before your code runs and retry. See `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculation and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating. At the end of your code, set them back.

Comment: @FunThomas think a slight typo `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` though remember if you're doing this you should put an error catch in that resets it to True

Comment: Firstly, I created a test range of 50000 rows and your code needs about three seconds. Secondly, Why do you proceed in this way? Wouldn't it be better to place a flag only on the second (third, fourth also...) and delete the duplicates after, using it? Am I missing something? If I am right, I can post a piece of code doing that in less than a second, I think.

Comment: @InjuredCoding: You're right. Saw this and the mismatching backquote chars too late and cannot edit the comment. Too tired to write it again - there is more than enough info here and elsewhere about this.

Comment: @FunThomas By using this option "Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual" the execution time is increased from 2 min.17 to 6 min 33 sec. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @InjuredCoding Thanks again for contributing.

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you for responding and on the other hand I explain and answer your question.

In this case it is important to set the flag to the original and duplicate record. What my report does is identify the records that have their pair and with this data I generate a new report and in parallel I eliminate them from the main report. I work in a bank and we receive millions of transactions to be paid and many of them are returned automatically and that is why I have to mark them so they are not considered in the final report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Flag Unique Values

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FlagUniques()

    ' Reference the worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    ' i.e. instead use e.g.
    'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Write the header.
    ws.Range("BE1") = "Flag_Unico"
    
    ' Reference the source (one-column) range.
    With ws.Range("BD2:BD" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row)
    
        ' Write the number of rows to a variable ('rCount').
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = .Rows.Count
    
        ' Write the values from the source range to the source array ('sData').
        Dim sData() As Variant: sData = .Value
        
        ' Reference a new dictionary object ('dict').
        With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            .CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case-insensitive; out-comment if not
            
            ' Write the unique values from the source array to the dictionary
            ' whose 'keys' will hold the unique value while each
            ' of the corresponding 'items' will hold the count.
            
            Dim r As Long ' Current Row
            
            For r = 1 To rCount
                .Item(sData(r, 1)) = .Item(sData(r, 1)) + 1
            Next r
            
            ' Write the 'True/False' results to the destination array ('dData').
            
            Dim dData() As Boolean: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)

            For r = 1 To rCount
                If .Item(sData(r, 1)) = 1 Then ' the count is '1'
                    dData(r, 1) = True
                'Else ' the count is '>1'; the default value is 'False'
                End If
            Next r
        
' Or:
'            ' Write the '1/0' results to the destination array ('dData').
'
'            Dim dData() As Long: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
'
'            For r = 1 To rCount
'                If .Item(sData(r, 1)) = 1 Then ' the count is '1'
'                    dData(r, 1) = 1
'                'Else ' the count is '>1'; the default value is '0'
'                End If
'            Next r
        
        End With
        
        ' Write the results from the destination array to the destination range.

        ' Reference the destination (one-column) range.
        With .EntireRow.Columns("BE")
            ' Write.
            .Value = dData
            ' Clear below.
            .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row - rCount + 1).Offset(rCount).Clear
        End With
        
    End With
            
    ' Inform to not wonder if the code has run or not.
    MsgBox "Unique values flagged.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. your code runs only in 05 sec!!!!. The only thing that I modified was the MSGBOX, I deactivated it!

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next way. It must be very fast using arrays and working only in memory, and a `Dictionary` to identify the unique cases. It will place a flag **only for the next occurrence (second, third, fourth and so on...)**. In this way it offers the possibility to sort by flag and delete duplicates, only unique cases remaining:

```
Sub findDuplicatesBis()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, arrBD, arrBE, i As Long, dict As Object
   
   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   arrBD = ws.Range("BD2:BD" & ws.cells(ws.rows.count, "BD").End(xlUp).row).Value2
   ReDim arrBE(1 To UBound(arrBD), 1 To 1)
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   For i = 1 To UBound(arrBD)
        If Not dict.Exists(arrBD(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arrBD(i, 1), 1
        Else
            arrBE(i, 1) = "Duplicate"
        End If
   Next i
   ws.Range("BE1") = "Flag_Unico"
   ws.Range("BE2").Resize(UBound(arrBE), 1).Value2 = arrBE
End Sub
```

Comment: FaneDuru, I ran the code but I don't have any response. It does not give me any results and it does not show the values in the designated column

Comment: On the other hand, I answered your question that you asked me lines above. ""Secondly, Why do you proceed in this way? Wouldn't it be better to place a flag only on the second (third, fourth also...) and delete the duplicates after, using it?""

Comment: @Micky Stone You answered my question 7 hours after I posted the above answer... The code can be easily adapted to return as you clarified. Not knowing the context I thought that this is what most of the people does/needs when searching for duplicates.